# How to rename a folder that contains smart quotes

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, character-encoding

I have a folder that was created automatically. The user unintentionally provided smart (curly) quotes as part of the name, and the process that sanitizes the inputs did not catch these. As a result, the folder name contains the smart quotes. For example:

```
this-is-my-folder’s-name-“Bob”
```

I'm now trying to rename/remove said folder on the command line, and none of the standard tricks for dealing with files/folders with special characters (enclosing in quotes, escaping the characters, trying to rename it by inode, etc.) are working. All result in:

```
mv: cannot move this-is-my-folder’s-name-“Bob” to this-is-my-folders-name-BOB: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone provide some advice as to how I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `rm -i -- this-is-*` ?

Comment: I believe backslash escaping of special character will resolve the problem. Use bash shell itself to complete the source folder name by pressing `tab` after typing few character of source folder. Then type the destination folder name.

Comment: You can always glob all the files (or a subset of the files) in an array, e.g., `files=( this-is-my-folder* )`. This creates an array `files`. Inspect this array with `declare -p files`. See at what index your file is; for example if you find it at index `42`, then `mv -- "${files[42]}" this-is-my-folders-name-BOB` will work. By the way, didn't TAB completion work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the name in a format you can copy-and-paste into your shell:

```
printf '%q\n' this*
```

...will print out the filename in a manner the shell will accept as valid input. This might look something like:

```
$'this-is-my-folder200\231s-name-200\234Bob200\235'
```

...which you can then use as an argument to `mv`:

```
mv $'this-is-my-folder200\231s-name-200\234Bob200\235' this-is-my-folders-name-BOB
```

---

Incidentally, if your operating system works the same way mine does (when running the test above), this would explain why using single-character globs such as `?` for those characters didn't work: They're actually more than one byte long each!

Comment: Wow! Fantastic. This helped me immensely with my MacOS command line (iterm2) problem where I could not possibly rename files and folders with (MacOS default) curly quotes in the filename. Using this technique I was able to get `Fred\342\200\231s MacBook Pro.sparsebundle` to rename as `Fred MacBook Pro.sparsebundle`, where the `\342\200\231` is the encoding for the curly single possessive quote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell globbing token `?` to match any single character, so matching the smart quotes using `?` should do:

```
mv this-is-my-folder?s-name-?Bob?  new_name
```

Here replacing the smart quotes with `?` to match the file name.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities.

- If an initial substring of the file name ending before the first quote is unique within the directory, then you can use filename completion to help you type an appropriate command.  Type "mv" (without the quotes) and the unique initial substring, then press the TAB key to request filename completion.  Bash will complete the filename with the correct characters, correctly escaped.
- Use a graphical file browser.  Then you can select the file to rename by clicking on it.  (Details of how to proceed from there depend on the browser.)  If you don't have a graphical terminal and can't get one, then you may be able to do the same with a text-mode browser such as Midnight Commander.
- A simple glob built with the `?` or `*` wildcard should be able to match the filename
- Use a more complex glob to select the filename, and perhaps others with the same problem.  Maybe something like `*[^a-zA-Z0-9-]*` would do.  Use a pattern substitution to assign a new name.  Something like this:

```
for f in *[^a-zA-Z0-9-]*; do
    mv "$f" "${f//[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/}"
done
```

The substitution replaces all appearances of a characters that are not decimal digits, appercase or lowercase Latin letters, or hyphens with nothing (i.e. it strips them).  Do take care before you use this, though, to make sure you're not going to make more changes than you intend to do.